# count of columns from more than two tables with out using full outer join

Tags: oracle, sybase, oracle-apex

I have 2 tables called tb1 and tb2 as below,

```
tb1
mtdata mtproject mtteam mtdetails 
a apple fruits 'fruits family'
a orange fruits 'fruits family'
b tomatto veg 'vegtable family'
b beatroot root 'vegtable family'
```

and

```
tb2 
mtproject rrequester rdate
apple x xxxxx 
orange y xxxxx 
apple xx xxxxx
apple xz xxxxx
```

I want to get the below details: mtdata,mtproject,mtteam,count(project) where rrequester in (x,y,z) as yes_count and count(project)where rrequester not in(x,y,z) No_count

please help me to get query with out using full outer join Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why anyone would use a full outer join when left join is all that's needed:

```
select tb1.mtdata
     , tb1.mtproject
     , tb1.mtteam
     , count(case when rrequester in ('x','y','z') then 1 else null end) yes_count
     , count(case when rrequester not in ('x','y','z') then 1 else null end) no_count
  from tb1
  left join tb2
    on tb1.mtproject = tb2.mtproject
 group by tb1.mtdata
     , tb1.mtproject
     , tb1.mtteam;
```

You can even get by without any outer joins by using scalar subqueries:

```
select tb1.mtdata
     , tb1.mtproject
     , tb1.mtteam
     , (select count(*) from tb2 where tb2.mtproject = tb1.mtproject and rrequester in ('x','y','z')) yes_count
     , (select count(*) from tb2 where tb2.mtproject = tb1.mtproject and rrequester not in ('x','y','z')) no_count
  from tb1;
```

Some caution should be taken with scalar sub queries since they can be less performant than the equivalent join operation.